# SQL Query to fetch distinct row based by making two columns data unique

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-workbench

```
Id  uid pid   weekNo  year
1    1  1      28    2014 
2    1  2      28    2014
3    1  3      29    2014
4    1  4      28    2015
5    1  5      28    2015
```

// Output Should Be this i.e by making  weekno and year as distinct

```
Id  uid pid   weekNo  year
1    1  1      28    2014 
3    1  3      29    2014
4    1  4      28    2015
```

Comment: But that is not really distinct.

Comment: What have you done so far to achieve this?

Comment: i mean (weekno,year) should be distinct

Answer (score 1):

If you dont care about values of id,uid,pid should come from same row than use below query to return distinct group of year and weekNo

```
SELECT MIN(Id),MIN(uid),MIN(pid),weekno,year
FROM tableName
GROUP BY weekno,year
```

Comment: sorry i have noting to do with id,uid pid data should be filterd based on distinct (weekno,year)

Comment: run the query , it will will satisfy your requiremnt

Comment: Gosh, lucky that row with the minimum value of one column corresponds to the row with the minimum value in another column.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to guarantee that the values all come from the *same* row, then you need a query such as:

```
select t.*
from table t
where not exists (select 1
                  from table t2
                  where t2.weekno = t.weekno and t2.year = t.year and t2.pid > t.pid
                 );
```

Answer (score -1):

Select * from tableName GROUP BY weekno,year;

Comment: I wanted to fetch the whole row so the above answer worked fine with me.

Comment: Group By wont do anything in this case.